# "offending key" warning when connecting by ssh to my VPS

Tags: linux, ssh

When I execute:

```
ssh root@myVPS
```

I'm getting the next warning:

```
Warning: the RSA host key for 'myVPS' differs from the key for the IP address 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx'
Offending key for IP in /home/manolo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Matching host key in /home/manolo/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

and if I type "yes" I works fine, but I don't know why this warning is thrown.
Any suggestion of why is it thrown and how to avoid it?

Comment: There are two different host keys for the same IP address in the known_hosts file, one of them matches the other one is outdated.

You can just use `vim +1 ~/.ssh/known_hosts` and remove the first line with :  dd 

The line where the offending key is located is the one after the colon, thus line 1 in this case.

Comment: `:1` means line 1, `:2` means line two. Offending key on line 1 is the line you need to delete.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Most likely, you'll have reinstalled your VPS at some point and kept the host name and/or IP address. When reinstalling, the host key of the VPS got regenerated and since it differs from the one in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, the warning gets displayed so you can detect the problem. This is done to prevent you from connecting to an entirely different system that replaces the legitimate host, e.g. to collect passwords.

If something like that happened, just remove the offending key from your `known_hosts` file and everything is fine, but if you are not aware of such an rinstall, you have to investigate further do understand why the key differs.

Comment: Yes. This is the case. But how to know what to remove in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. There are a lot of letters in this file.

Comment: You can remove them with `ssh-keygen -R`, see the man page for more infos.

Comment: All right! I've done `ssh-keygen -R ip_address` and warning have disappeared.

Comment: I am facing this issue while doing an ssh to my server which is a dedicated ubuntu machine. I don't think that anything on that server was changed recently. But since there are many people using this machine with sudo access I cannot be very sure. Can someone point me how should I ensure that nothing was compromised?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and it is very easy to resolve. Please open your known_hosts file from `vi .ssh/known_hosts` and search for your server name. If you find the host key is there without the IP address, then add your IP to that file and it will resolve your issue.
Before:

```
myVPS ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAsIfCSqA2rSlTvH8AMrMjpD66y5dOsYOPp30AXYGAEAFkVBs1+51lbRNyiFenpbxOyQjyvpgVJdkC4kqgG66xE6IPBrqpUFL3KjbUCTZ8sNHWn+I89bAMWDzGEiqaad/powDxgZgFe74bV82Se1igbFmHlHwwb7DEAcjXh34XbcMgJ0vIExJqPV1zccKkCXhstQy7av0+I7GRz5wIbYiIFMungKIhX3upwQOzyW/E1RDmq89BRv1g2ch1xsKK5OpNjCCFP2OSYPybJmFXhjOWI7LUdFASmaw5Z1az9LLpLKQePQ4mWsL/ON8Z9uvzhQig3hdQ/cnrAsRLShn4rJratw==
```

After adding IP:

```
myVPS,198.51.100.42 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAsIfCSqA2rSlTvH8AMrMjpD66y5dOsYOPp30AXYGAEAFkVBs1+51lbRNyiFenpbxOyQjyvpgVJdkC4kqgG66xE6IPBrqpUFL3KjbUCTZ8sNHWn+I89bAMWDzGEiqaad/powDxgZgFe74bV82Se1igbFmHlHwwb7DEAcjXh34XbcMgJ0vIExJqPV1zccKkCXhstQy7av0+I7GRz5wIbYiIFMungKIhX3upwQOzyW/E1RDmq89BRv1g2ch1xsKK5OpNjCCFP2OSYPybJmFXhjOWI7LUdFASmaw5Z1az9LLpLKQePQ4mWsL/ON8Z9uvzhQig3hdQ/cnrAsRLShn4rJratw==
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear both the hostname and the ip address from your known_hosts file, you can do it like this:

```sh
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R [somehostname.net]
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R [123.123.123.123]
```

Just replace `somehostname.net` with the hostname or domain name of the host you want to clear, and replace the ip address with the hosts ip address (leave the square brackets in). If it worked you will see a message like this:

```
/home/yourname/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /home/yourname/.ssh/known_hosts.old
```

If it didn't work, try the same thing but without the square brackets, also double check that the hostname and ip address is correct:

```sh
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R somehostname.net
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R 123.123.123.123
```

If the host's SSH port is on a different port, say 2222 instead of 22 then simply add the port like so:

```sh
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R [somehostname.net]:2222
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R [123.123.123.123]:2222
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the warning has already been explained in other answers.

For "how to avoid it" here are my two cents:

The "feature" to warn about such changes is in my opinion mostly an annoying bug since so far I do not know of away to say "I know - leave me alone with that warning in the future".

The error message e.g. might also appear simply because you assign two different names to a host with the same IP address. Any time you start addressing it with a different name the error message will appear and you will be asked for an action. I'd love to see this changed so any comments are welcome on how to fix this. If there are positive comments this answer might well move to a separate question.

Comment: If you have a system whose SSH key legitimately keeps changing, you might write a `Host` block for it in your `~/.ssh/config` file, with settings `StrictHostKeyChecking no` and `UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null`. But that means you can then be trivially Man-in-the-Middle attacked when connecting to that particular host, so consider carefully where to use this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error like this:

```
Warning: the RSA host key for 'myVPS' differs from the key for the IP address 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx'
Offending key for IP in /home/manolo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Matching host key in /home/manolo/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

just delete line 1 in your known_hosts file. Then next time you run the git commant it will add the hew RSA host hey.